# How to handle a reopen review on a question closed as a duplicate of a now-deleted question?

Tags: support, review-queues, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

This just came up in the review queue: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4935843

This question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403141/online-compiler-for-c-assembly) is closed as a duplicate of this deleted question: [Is there an online gcc service like ideone.com that can show program disassembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266314/is-there-an-online-gcc-service-like-ideone-com-that-can-show-program-disassembly)

Whilst the original question is off topic for StackOverflow, it's closed as a duplicate of a question which is no longer visible for users without enough reputation.

I've specified that I believe that this should be reopened (purely so that afterwards it can be closed for the *recommending a specific tool* reason).

Should this be flagged instead?

Shouldn't the system be detecting questions like this and somehow amending them automatically?

Comment: Once I reviewed a question in the CVQ that had 4 votes to close as a duplicate of a deleted question. There were tons of potential duplicate targets but at that point any close vote guaranteed it would point at the deleted question..

Comment: Would it be a bad idea to link to http://assembly.ynh.io/ in a comment on these questions though?  It _is_ useful information, off-topic or no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original was deleted by a moderator (for good reason). Since this question also has the same reasons to be deleted, I've deleted it.